# How to fix "no instance of overloaded function" in vector push_back?

Tags: c++, c++11, visual-c++

I want to write a function which takes as input a pointer to a vector pointer which point to a string (Dictionary) and a pointer which points to a char (p). The function will check if the char is in the Dictionary and if it isn't there it adds the p in the vector Dictionary.

My code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
using std::string;
using std::vector;

std::vector<string *> dictionary;

void manageDictionary(vector<string *> * dictionary, char *p) {
    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < (*dictionary).size(); i++) {
        string * pstring = (*dictionary).at(i);
        if ((*pstring).compare(p)) {
            (*dictionary).push_back(p);
        }
    }
}
```

However, the visual studio compiler shows I have an error in the if statement just before the push_back method (`.`). When I hover on the error, it says "no instance of overloaded function".

I added the `std::vector<string *> dictionary;` at the beginning, still cannot figure out where the problem is.

Comment: How do you expect the compiler to convert a `char*` (what `p` is) to a `string*` (what the vector contains)?

Comment: It's highly unlikely that you want a vector of pointers, or that you need to pass the vector to the function via a pointer.

Comment: At first glance, there are way too many pointers in there for C++ code.

Comment: `std::set<std::string>` might be useful.

Comment: This would be easier to read if you wrote `p->foo` rather than `(*p).foo`.

Comment: You would make life a lot easier by stopping with the use of pointers

Comment: You don't need pointers.

Answer (score 1):

`dictionnary` is a vector of `std::string*`. `std::string*` and `char*` are totally unrelated types. To convert from `char*` to `std::string*` will require you to create a new `string` that contains the value of `p` for your dictionnary, rather than passing a `char*` directly. This change  will allow your example to compile, but the resulting function is error prone.

```
#include <string>
#include <vector>
using std::string;
using std::vector;

void manageDictionnary(vector<string *> * dictionnary, char *p) {
    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < (*dictionnary).size(); i++) {
        string * pstring = (*dictionnary).at(i);
        if ((*pstring).compare(p)) {
            (*dictionnary).push_back(new string(p));
            // Make a new string     ^^^^^^^^^^
        }
    }
}
```

This solution will require you to delete your strings manually which is not the way things are done in c++. Changing from `std::vector<std::string*>` to simply `std::vector<std::string>` will solve this problem, and avoid you headaches in the future. There are other unnecessary pointers that can be removed. Since `at(i)` returns a `string&` then we should change `pstring` to `string&`. Since `dictionnary` is not optional (can't be `nullptr`) and always points to the same `vector` we can also change it to a `vector<string>&`.

```
void manageDictionnary(vector<string> & dictionnary, char *p) {
    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < dictionnary.size(); i++) {
        string & pstring = dictionnary.at(i);
        if (pstring.compare(p)) {
            dictionnary.push_back(p);
        }
    }
}
```

This latest version will work fine and is much more in line with c++'s philosophy for resource management. I recommend you read on a few topics :

- Standard algorithms like [`std::find`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/find).
- [Range-based for loops](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/range-for).
- [const-correctness](https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/const-correctness).
- [pointer vs reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57483/what-are-the-differences-between-a-pointer-variable-and-a-reference-variable-in).

Additionally, consider using [`std::set<string>`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/set) or [`std::unordered_set<string>`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_set) for a more convenient representation of a dictionnary.

In the future, note that the preferred way to access a pointer's methods is `ptr->foo()` rather than `(*ptr).foo()`.